# Automating filling and submitting an HTML form using PHP? Is it possible?

Tags: php, database

I am afraid this is sort of a vague question and might be down-voted but I will still ask it. What I want to achieve is filling out text fields of some website (which has no API) using PHP. Like for example (not what I want to do) filling out text in the status bar of facebook or filling out username password fields of a website. Is this achievable?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This can be done with curl POST, but would be difficult for facebook as would need tobe logged in & suspect there are measures in place that detect such things to prevent spam.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, no, this is not generally possible. PHP is typically used on the server side. What you're referring to (i.e.: modifying controls on a web site) occurs on the client side, so you would probably use a language such as JavaScript. However, there are limitations to being able to use JavaScript on a web page that's not yours. For what your purposes, you might need to create an entire browser extension… and that's an entirely different animal.

Comment: Or use an extension, such as Greasemoney for FF.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with curl POST

**Example:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path/to/form");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'username' => 'joe',
    'password' => 'blogsy'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**

The `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` line is not actually necessary but it means the HTML from the web page returned goes into the `$output` variable rather than echoed out to standard output.

**CURLOPT_POST**

The `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` line tells CURL that this is POST instead of the default GET.

**CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**

The $data array contains the POST field values the equivalent HTML form value for this might be something like:

```
<input type='text' name='username' value='joe' />
<input type='password' name='password' value='blogsy' />
```

Comment: is it some how possible to click the "Submit" button?

Answer (score 0):

If you can inject a java-script code then you can. Or simply get the HTML code from the site you want and simply add a value tag for the needed fields.